# Installing a Chilli HotSpot with phpmyprepaid

Tags: server, apache2

I'm installing a Chilli hotspot on Ubuntu Server and I'm trying to use it with phpmyprepaid, but I can't get it working.

The Chilli part is fine, but i can't access the install of phpmyprepaid. I'm downloading it and unzipping in `/var/www` but it always tells me that it's not found.

Would anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract it on `/var/www/html/`.